# In a while True loop reading a RPi GPIO need the time a switch was closed and then when the state changed to open

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm new to Python so please be kind.  I have basic code working to know when the input state of #18 on the RPi GPIO is such that a switch closed.  What I'd like is the best (easiest) method to capture the time when the switch is closed and then not closed (opened).

My end objective is to write to a file when the sail switch closes and then when it opens to a data file to monitor when there is air flow indicating the A/C is running.  I already have the openweathermap API working to gather the temperature and a print of a literal when the switch is closed which just keeps redisplaying in the while loop.  My time.sleep will be 60 seconds.  The file will eventually have all of the start/stop times for several days as well as the temperature.

Answer (score 1):

You if you want to measure time delta between open/close you can use `time` module, more specific `time.time()` function. If you want to record date and time of switching, use `datetime` module with `datetime.datetime.now()` function.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm already using datetime and it works well even with math.  My problem is to record the times when the switch closed and then opened (air conditioning goes off) after it opens (it's normally open when the A/C isn't running).  Then continue to monitor and write the results to a file for each cycle.  I'm going to let it run for a week to determine the on/off pattern.  There will likely be more than 100 cycles.

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem. Why you can't just get current time when it closes and then when it opens again and calculate difference to get amout of time in closed state?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing a for loop (1,n) where n is a large number and then two loops: a while True if input_state == False followed by a while True: if input _state == True.  Each while has a counter increment.  More code to get temperature from openweathermap, get some variables, write an output file and sleep but you get the idea.

Basically done - just waiting for more ordered hardware.

Comment: That's basically implementing a tight polling loop for a condition that's already explicitly event driven. This will most certainly cause your CPU load to spike while polling and as a pattern is best avoided. You are much better off sampling `datetime.now()` whenever you flip the switch state in the GPIO event handler as kacpo1 suggested, then you can decide whether to cache the times, compute the deltas, write them out to a file, etc.